# Scope of operator->

Tags: c++, scope, operator-overloading

When overloading operator `->`, one would eventually have to return a pointer. If this pointer points to an object created inside the function like:

```
struct Something {
  char c;
  Something(char k){
    c = k;
  }
};
struct Hello {
  int a;
  Something* operator->(){
    Something s(a);
    return &s;
  }
};
```

Would then dereferencing this result in undefined behavior (as [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794)):

```
Hello h {5};
cout << h->c;
```

If so, can this be resolved, still using `operator->`?

Comment: why do you want to do that? you may add static keyword, it will work but I do not understand your SW design.

Comment: @nivpeled It's far more complicated than this question to address.

Comment: `operator->` is a perfectly normal function. The name and the syntax are somewhat unusual but they are just sugar.

Comment: `inline` has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would then dereferencing this result in undefined behavior?

Yes.

> If so, can this be resolved, still using `operator->`?

The following applies to any other member function.

Create `Something` instance as a member of `Hello`. Then the pointer to it remains valid for the duration of `Hello`'s lifetime. You can construct `Something` from the integer you are storing immediately, so you can get rid of it.

If `Something` takes additional resources (memory, handles, etc.), you probably want to construct it at the time of `operator->` call. You can choose `std::unique_ptr` (dynamic) or `std::optional` (static) for this. Or, if `Something` supports an uninitialized state (e.g. default-constructed), you can initialize (e.g. move-assign) to it later.

---

If you cannot alter `Hello` class then your only option is to overload `operator->` to return by `Something` by value directly.

But, I must say, the circumstances of this problem are starting to get weird and the way of overloading operators even more so.

Comment: Did you return `std::shared_ptr` or just raw pointer? What did not work with `std::unique_ptr`?